# Ruby misses XPath expression when listening on interface

Tags: ruby, docker

For API-testing I am listening on an interface that sends messages every second.
On my lokal machine the tests run fine. I have an eightcore processor with 16GB of Ram.
When running the test in a Dockercontainer on my machine everything is still fine. (I ran the tests 3000 times - everything was good)
As soon as I put the docker container on a different host (2 core with 6 gb - only 2 GB are used by the tests) some of the tests fail sometimes.
This happens quite often - every 15th iteration or so.

Now I am wondering what could be the cause.

Here is the code snippet.
Sorry - not S.O.L.I.D. ... I'm still learning :-)

```
def wait_for(xpath_exp, timeout=$timeout)
  puts 'Waiting for xpath-expression'
  begin
    Timeout::timeout(timeout) do
      $logger.info "#{@name} waiting #{timeout} seconds for message satisfying '#{xpath_exp}'"
      loop do
        puts 'waiting for message'
        msg = @connection.gets(0x4.chr).chomp(0x4.chr)
        doc = Nokogiri::XML(msg)
        if not doc.xpath(xpath_exp).empty?
          $logger.info "#{@name} encountered message matching '#{xpath_exp}': #{msg}'"
          @@result = 0
          return doc
        end
      end
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    $logger.error e
    $logger.error "waited for '#{xpath_exp}' - no messages received -   timed out after #{timeout} seconds."
    $logger.error "terminating."
    Process.exit(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: what is @connection?

Comment: It's a TCPSocket

Comment: Do you see any errors in the log?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say - as I found out nothing in the code above is wrong.
It was a timeout somewhere else in the tests that made the tests quit before time...